# Using a stored proceedure in multiple triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

In addition to the notes table, I am applying this same trigger to around 15 other tables. Not sure, but seems like a stored procedure will eliminate the duplicated code.  Is this a good application for a stored procedure?  If so, how could it be implemented?

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_notes_ins BEFORE INSERT ON notes FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.created_by_user IS NULL OR NEW.created_by_user = '' THEN
        SET NEW.created_by_user = @users_id;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.modified_by_user IS NULL OR NEW.modified_by_user = '' THEN
        SET NEW.modified_by_user = @users_id;
    END IF;
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER tg_notes_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON notes FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.modified_by_user = OLD.modified_by_user THEN
        SET NEW.modified_by_user = @users_id;
    END IF;
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not claiming this is how to do it, but it seems to work, and would appreciate any opinions.  Thanks

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `createRecord` ()
BEGIN
    IF NEW.created_by_user IS NULL OR NEW.created_by_user = '' THEN
        SET NEW.created_by_user = @users_id;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.modified_by_user IS NULL OR NEW.modified_by_user = '' THEN
        SET NEW.modified_by_user = @users_id;
    END IF;
END$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `modifyRecord` ()
BEGIN
    IF NEW.modified_by_user = OLD.modified_by_user THEN
        SET NEW.modified_by_user = @users_id;
    END IF;
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER tg_notes_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON notes FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL createRecord();
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER tg_notes_ins BEFORE INSERT ON notes FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL modifyRecord();
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```